# Arduino and ball position

Tags: position, arduino, sensors

I'm looking for some way to detect a position of the ball on 2D surface. On this video it's doing by web-camera, but is there any other way to detect ball position?
http://youtu.be/0DqcnHE6r9M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the positions of things in numerous ways on a 2D surface.

Generally this is done using a camera, as it is very easy to detect the position of objects in an image.

Although the other ways of doing it are very diverse and creative, and I cannot possibly list them all here, a couple that come to mind:

- You can use a laser range-finder to get a 2D distance measurement from some point in 180 degrees on the side of the 2D plane, which can be used to determine the position of the ball.
- You can use some sort of pressure sensor underneath the board - perhaps a sensitive grid of sensors - to get the approximate location.